# I want to pass the name of a calling web page in a form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am quite new to Ruby. I have a landing page controller and index page that has a button on it that pops up a user input form for email addresses, etc. One of the things I want to capture and write into the database is the name of the originating landing page.

For example:

```
www,mydomain.com/landngpage/campaign1
```

Another landing page could be:

```
www,mydomain.com/landngpage/campaign2
```

The above form calls a `ppc_user` controller

```
www,mydomain.com/lppc_user/new
```

Can anyone help me on this? I have seen a few examples of passing data using the flash option, but I can't get this to work.

Comment: Do you mean `www`**`.`**`mydomain.com/landpage/campaign1`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for `request.referer`.

It tells you from which page the user comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden field and in fill it with an instance variable created in the controller...

so in your controller index:

```
def index
    @campaign = params[:campaign] # this is whatever parameter you have named that is "campaign1", "campaign2", etc..
end
```

then in your form:

```
hidden_field :campaign, @campaign
```

or with the answer given by apneadiving:

```
hidden_field :campaign, request.referer
```

and then whatever controller you are posting your message to will have a param called :campaign containing the URI that it came from or the name of the campaign parameter depending on which one you choose to use.